# How can you implement a refractive surcface in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

What is the best way to implement a refractive surface in OpenGL? I would like to specify that a particular polygon functions like a lens, having translucency and refracting light passing through it.

I am aware that translucency alone may be achieved through alpha-blending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need ray-tracing to properly implement refraction.

You can use OpenGL to render the results of the ray-trace, and there are several GPGPU ray-tracers floating around, but those would use OpenCL or CUDA -- there's nothing in the OpenGL API that helps with implementing ray-tracing or refraction specifically.

Comment: Is that true even if I don't need realistic refraction? A blunt approximation that looks good enough for a game would work.

Comment: @Erward: I guess you could render the scene to a PBO, calculate which part of it would appear through the refraction, and render it as a texture (with texture mapping providing the spatial transformation).

Comment: A similar approach of what Ben Voigt suggested involves the use of a cube map, which allow to add some corrections by the incoming vector and the relative position of the vertex/fragment to the cube map center. Just take a look at some of the refraction demos at http://developer.nvidia.com

Comment: another idea I had was to apply a scaling matrix to everything except the lens, render the scene, copy the region corresponding to the lens to the stencil buffer, and then re-render without scaling, stenciling in the portion from the first pass. Do you think this is feasible?